# Holo Theme and SDK minimum

Tags: android, android-studio

setting the sdk minimum 15, should I use Theme.Holo and not Theme.AppCompat

And instead, it is always as if I had given compatibility for Android versions 2.1 and higher.

In this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

when I have to add the search action, the ActionBar, are forced to use xmlns: yourapp = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
to be able to give the right showAsAction ...

Same problem to set the Holo theme, this is not available, and returns me error (You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme with this activity), and are forced to use AppCompat.

I then tried to create a new project with SDK minimun 16, thinking that the problem was on the 15th, and when I go to
res \ values ​​\ styles.xml
I always find parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

The only way to use Holo, is creating a project with minimum 21 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to not use AppCompat is to not use AppCompat. If you extend `ActionBarActivity` you have to use a theme that inherits from `Theme.AppCompat`. If you want to use Holo themes, you have to extend `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail.
What do you advise me to do? I'm working on API 21 (5.0.1), all right then if I use AppCompat?

Comment: Depends what you want to do, What is the minimum sdk version you want to support? Do you want to support material design on anything lower than 21?

Comment: I set Minimum SDK = 15
But Android Studio created the activity extension ActionBarActivity
For now, no, I only need the API 21.
But in case, I should also support older versions with the material designe, I'll just refer always to AppCompat?

Comment: Yes, if you want to support material design on anything lower than 21, you should use AppCompat. You may not need it now, but if you _ever_ want to, you may as well do it now, because it's not straightforward to change afterwards. It's not rocket science, but it's tedious.

Comment: Well well: D
Thank you so much for your advice: D